# Why does this way of creating dynamically a button on jquery after appending it to DOM creates objects?

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamically-generated

I dont understand why 1º option of code works but 2º doesnt!? Using an string to create the button element works fine, but using 2º argument of jquery selector to create the button element + its properties doesnt work. It just create and attach objects to DOM

```
<script>
var arr = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
  // 1º option to create button elem
  var boton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn- 
  primary">'+i+'</button>';
  // 2º option to create button elem
  var boton = $('<button>', {
    'text': i,
    'id': 'btn_' + i,
    'class': 'btn btn-danger'
  })
  arr.push(boton);
}


$(function(){

  $('button').after(arr.join(''));

});


</script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Imprimir en consola 'Hola Mundo'
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method works because you create a string containing valid HTML.

The second example attempts to create a string from jQuery object. This will not work as you expect because it implicitly calls `toString()` on the object which results in `"[Object object]"`, not HTML.

Note that the latter method, using jQuery objects, can be made to work if you remove the `join()` call and append the array itself:

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  var boton = $('<button>', {
    'text': i,
    'id': 'btn_' + i,
    'class': 'btn btn-danger'
  })
  arr.push(boton);
}

$(function() {
  $('button').after(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Imprimir</button>
```

I would also suggest not creating incremental `id` attributes on dynamic content as it generally tends to make code more complex than it needs to be. Use common classes instead, along with DOM traversal methods and data attributes. The best approach will however be completely dependant on your specific use case.